# Splitting string into sub strings

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, split

During an automation script written in legacy PHP, I got the following string

```
string '<br /><select id="addid8231736" name="addid8231736" size="1" >
<option value="" selected="true">Select an option</option>
<option value="11518065" data-qty="5"> 11 - PKR11099.59</option>
<option value="11518063" data-qty="1"> 9 - PKR9850.00</option>' 
(length=246)
```

this string would be an variable length and variable option string, My ultimate desire it to get options from this like

prices

- PKR11099.59
- PKR9850.00

and

size ids

- 11
- 9

**SO FAR**
I am at success to have this

```
string 'Select an option 11 - PKR11099.59 9 - PKR9850.00' (length=48)
```

through string tags..

Can somebody Please help me get my desired options??

thanks to all of you guys..

**UPDATE**

I tried exploding it throug `explode("</option><option", $options_data1);`
and got this

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '<br/><select id="addid8231736" name="addid8231736" size="1"><option value="" selected="true">Select an option' (length=109)
  1 => string ' value="11518065" data-qty="5"> 11 - PKR11099.59' (length=48)
  2 => string ' value="11518063" data-qty="1"> 9 - PKR9850.00</option>' (length=55)
```

Comment: @CBroe not getting you

Comment: _“SO FAR I am at success to have this”_ – show us what you did to get this far …

Comment: I had a little function which string down the html tags, willing to post them if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = <<<EOS
<br /><select id="addid8231736" name="addid8231736" size="1" >
<option value="" selected="true">Select an option</option>
<option value="11518065" data-qty="5"> 11 - PKR11099.59</option>
<option value="11518063" data-qty="1"> 9 - PKR9850.00</option>
EOS;
preg_match_all('~<option.*?>\s*(\d+)\s*-\s*(.*?)</option>~',$string,$matches);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <option value="11518065" data-qty="5"> 11 - PKR11099.59</option>
            [1] => <option value="11518063" data-qty="1"> 9 - PKR9850.00</option>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => PKR11099.59
            [1] => PKR9850.00
        )

)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, one little request ( please explain the regex too so that I can learn this art), How can I get Only the ID like 11 and 9?? thanks for this help

Comment: @NewBee The data is in `$matches` and it's a regular multi-dim array. For example, Id "11" is `$matches[1][0]` just like the output shows.

Comment: ..Saw that..was confused for one reason, I can use for loop for known number of elements, but my string would have variable number of items at different times, so was thinking that regex might give me a general solution..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue? You can use `count($matches[1])` to find out how many ids there are, so you can know what number to use in a `for` loop. Alternatively, you can just use a `foreach` loop and not have to care about finding out how many ids there are.

Comment: trying to extract only '[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 9
        )' how can I do it?